# Does D&D 5e have rules for gaining experience from gold?

Tags: dnd-5e, osr

I have read in some of the Old-School Basic D&D incarnations that characters are awarded more XP for the gold value of the treasure they find than they gain by defeating enemies. I like how this makes the players think more about avoiding fights and coming up with clever plans to collect the loot.

My question is, I haven't got to see much of the new D&D Next (I've only heard that Wizards of the Coast took elements from older versions) and I wanted to know if they emphasized more on loot or stuck with creatures for XP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In D&D next, Experience and tracking experience is [just one way to play.](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ll/20140217)
You can track XP through killing monsters, or through advancement in plot. Or you can not track XP at all.

While they will not have any modules published which will be balanced around treasure or gold equaling XP, you can easily implement that method of counting, since the game itself will not require any specific method.

The biggest concern I would have is that gold and treasure will be sparse, such that you would buy an upgraded set of armor for 500 gold or 5,000 gold, but those pieces of equipment are not meant to be affordable for 5-10 levels of play.  As @HerbN suggests below, you can fix this by giving 1 XP for 1 SP rather than for 1 gold.

Comment: One solution to your last problem is move the treasure experience down one coin type.  I tend to keep the GP economy but reward treasure XP at a rate of 1 SP = 1 XP.